# Android: Creating folder does not work

Tags: android, directory

I Want to take a photo and save it in the external storage, but the folder creation fails. 
Permission is set.

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
File.separator + "DCIM" + File.separator + "ScannerApp");
                if(!folder.exists()){
                    folder.mkdirs();
                }
```

Help please :)

Comment: "the folder creation fails" -- how **exactly** have you determined this?

Comment: What error or exception are you getting? Please put it in your question

Comment: Ok, my question is asked poorly. I want to create the folder to save a picture there. If i run that code the folder just gets not created on the phone, but I dont get any exceptions or something. Just not folder

Comment: have you used runtime permissions if you developing against MM? Is it a custom rom for example lineage os?

Comment: Whats does MM mean?

Comment: Its like the Folder gets created during the runtime, because the if() gets not touched. But I cant find the folder on the phone after.

Answer (score 0):

use this code below to initialize `folder` value:

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM" + File.separator + "ScannerApp");
```

or

```
File folder = new File(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM"), "ScannerApp");
```

Answer (score -1):

Replace this

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
File.separator + "DCIM" + File.separator + "ScannerApp");
                if(!folder.exists()){
                    folder.mkdirs();
                }
```

with

```
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() +
                    File.separator + "DCIM" + File.separator + "ScannerApp");
            if(!folder.exists()){
                folder.mkdirs();
            }
```

The problem is that you are using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` which will not return the path. Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()` to get the path.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This doesn't work, I get an error: **/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/com.my.application/  (No such file or directory)**

Comment: @Ganapolsky You are adding an extra / in the end. Also please check if your device is letting you create a folder in DCIM directory and you have taken the external storage permission.

Comment: I have a Google Pixel XL, so it doesn't let me

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Sorry for the late reply. Check if your phone allows other apps to create a folder under DCIM. If it allows creating then try creating a folder in any other directory using your app.